# How to write having query in yii?

Tags: yii

how to write distance query in yii,I have lat and lng distance in one table,but want to show details in other table,

In model i wrote like these,

```
public function relations() {       
    return array(
        'offerimage' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'OfferImage', 'offer_id'),
        //'wiffy_offer' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'WiffyMemberOffer', 'off_id'),
        'wiffy_offer' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'WiffyMemberOffer', 'off_id',
            'condition'=>'wiffy_offer.uid='.Yii::app()->user->id,
            'order'=>'wiffy_offer.id DESC'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'User','uid'),
        'merchant'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Merchant',array('uid'=>'uid')),
'offermerchant' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Merchant', 'uid',
'condition'=>' ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-3.58) ) * cos( radians( offermerchant.city_lat ) ) * cos( radians( offermerchant.city_lng ) - radians(55.466646) ) + sin( radians(-3.52) ) * sin( radians( offermerchant.city_lat ) ) ) ) As distance'),
 );         );
}
```

In controller,

```
   public function actionOffersdetails($id){
   $log_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
   if(User::model()->isWiffy())
    {
        $addedoffers = WiffyMemberOffer::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('uid' => Yii::app()->user->id));
        foreach ($addedoffers as $offers) {
            $offerids[] = $offers->off_id;
        }

        $criteria->addNotInCondition('t.offer_id', $offerids);
    }

    else
    {

        $criteria->addCondition("uid='{$log_id}'");

    }  

        $criteria->addCondition("to_date>='{$dates}'");

        $criteria->with = array('offermerchant');
      $criteria->having = 'offermerchant.distance < 4';
      $criteria->addCondition("to_date>='{$dates}'"); 
     $offerdet = Offers::model()->findAll($criteria);
   }
```

I got error like these,

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'As distance)' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`offer_id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`uid` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`offer_title` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`no_of_users` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`from_date` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`to_date` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`ex_offer_price`
```

What's wrong in my code?How to calculate distance?

In Merchant table having lat and lng value,and other table offer details i want to show.

Comment: show a few more code ...all the related action code, is better

Comment: Ya i added my whole relation code

Comment: I asked for the code  Controller  in the action you use for set the criteria..

Comment: Added my controller code too

Comment: try make sql which run on your database then convert it into yii.I think your CDbCriteria is wrong.

Comment: Plz tell me offermerchant my relation coding is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to calculate the distance.

MySQL:

```
$query = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `Longitude`)* pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515 ) as distance FROM `YourTable` WHERE distance >= ".$distance.";
```

The good practice for the use of "Having" is with "Group by" function. Instead of you can use the "Where". Something like mentioned below in Yii.

You can use `$criteria->condition() or $criteria->addCondition()`

Hope it will help.